# Buildroot Zero-W wireless

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, buildroot

Has anyone got WiFi working in buildroot for the Raspberry Pi Zero W? I can't find any online notes or walkthroughs on it.

The *raspberrypi0_defconfig* works fairly well, but doesn't include wireless.

I'm using the latest iteration of buildroot, 2017-08. 
I've added the rpi-wifi-firmware. Which packages are needed as a bare minimum to connect to a WiFi network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that an incorrect /etc/network/interfaces and/or /etc/wpa_supplicant was to blame. In between builds I've been adding additional packages, so I'm not 100% sure if these are all needed, but anyway these are the ones I included:

**Hardware Handling**

`Hardware Handling -> Firmware -> linux-firmware -> Broadcom BRCM bcm43xxx
Hardware Handling -> Firmware -> rpi-firmware (extended 'x' firmware)
Hardware Handling -> Firmware -> Install DTB overlays
Hardware Handling -> Firmware -> rpi-wifi-firmware
Hardware Handling -> dbus
Hardware Handling -> dbus-glib`

**Networking applications**

`Networking applications -> dhcpd
Networking applications -> ifupdown scripts
Networking applications -> iproute2
Networking applications -> iptables
Networking applications -> wireless-tools (+install shared lib)
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Enable 80211 support
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Enable EAP
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Install wpa_cli binary
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Install wpa_client shared library
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Install wpa_passphrase binary`

I don't think any other categories are relevant to WiFi networking.

**/etc/network/interfaces**

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

**/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf**

`ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
network={
ssid="OpenWrt"
psk=<your psk key here>
}`

**After boot I run:**

`wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -W -D nl80211, wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_cli -B -i wlan0 -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant -a /sbin/wpa_action
dhcpcd -q -w`

I want networking to come up well after boot as it's embedded linux and some more important stuff needs to start first. Therefore I'll add it to some post boot script somewhere. If you want to have your interface up at boot, then add these to your boot process somewhere. I'll consider this out of the scope for this question.

So, this works, it's not perfect, but it will be a good starting point for those that like me struggled. I am pretty sure not all mentioned packages are the bare minimum, also /sbin/wpa_action doesn't exist, but when leaving it out you'll enter interactive mode. I'll be refining this answer once I have a better grip on it. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 10):

I also tried to find the "bare minimum wireless" for RPi Zero W using buildroot so this Q&A came quite high on the search results. Eventhough the original answer was somewhat helpful, it's definitely not the best one so I though it would be worth sharing my own findings:

Using buildroot 2018.02.2

```
make raspberrypi0_defconfig
```

to clean you config. Then (*make menuconfig* and) select following from **Target packages**:

```
Hardware Handling -> Firmware -> rpi-wifi-firmware
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant
Networking applications -> wpa_supplicant - Enable 80211 support
```

Everything else that's necessary should already be pre-selected.

Then at **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  pre-up wpa_supplicant -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
  post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

and at **/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
   ssid="My WLAN"
   psk="my_wlan_password"
}
```

and now we're still missing the secret ingredient: the wifi driver must be loaded before the networking init-scripts kick in. You *could* **Enable WCHAR support** (at Toolchain -menu) in order to have **eudev** as */dev management* (at System configuration -menu) which would automatically handle the driver loading. Actually I recommend this if you're going to connect UBS devices to your RPi....

...but if not, edit **/etc/inittab** and **modprobe brcmfmac** yourself just before the rc scripts are ran:

```
...
# Load Wifi driver
::sysinit:/sbin/modprobe brcmfmac 

# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
...
```

That's it.

---

**UPDATE 21.03.2022**. Using the latest buildroot from `git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot` it seems that there are some changes:

1. `rpi-wifi-firmware` is renamed to `brcmfmac-sdio-firmware-rpi-wifi` which can be found under `brcmfmac_sdio-firmware-rpi` at Hardware Handling.
2. Line `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant` at `wpa_supplicant.conf` doesn't seem to be valid nor necessary anymore (if it ever even was)

I also found that if the wifi is needed for access over SSH, `OpenSSH` should be paired with `haveged` for faster random generator initialization. Without it the boottime can be minutes!

To fully prepare the board for direct headless access and considering all above, I made an external buildroot library with rpi-wifi package which handles all the necessary configuring from wifi setup to SSH config:

[rpi-wifi at my buildroot-externals repo](https://github.com/sirsipe/buildroot-externals#package-raspberrypi-wifi-rpi-wifi)

Comment: Should above configuration provide DHCP negotiation too? I currently have to run `udhcpc -i wlan0` manually to get an IP address.

Comment: @Jaakko, yes it should or at least it did for me. It also worked with 2019-something version of buildroot few weeks ago, but compared to 2018.02.2 there was a separate defconfig for raspberry Pi zero and zero W. Not sure when that was introduced.

Comment: Yes, it started working after a boot. Not sure what I messed up.